# Overloading a function to use an rvalue reference instead of an lvalue reference

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy, move-constructor

I am creating a doubly linked list template and I have to write 2 constructors where we pass in a linked list, and then construct a new list that has the same number of nodes as well as the same numbers in those nodes. The memory locations of the nodes will be the only difference between the two.

I have two constructors. One is a copy constructor that accepts a `List&` and a move constructor that accepts a `List&&`:

```cpp
List(const List &rhs);
List(List &&rhs);
```

Now my question is, the code is the same for both since it's not a shallow copy, right? The distinction is only for compilation purposes? My understanding is I do not need to `std::move` to implement the second constructor.

The purpose of the second constructor is to be able to create a list that uses a temporary object as its argument such as: `L1 = L2+ L3` where `L2+L3` becomes a temporary list that is deleted once its been assigned to `L1`.

Comment: Why would you *copy* anything in `List(List &&rhs);`? The whole point of the overload is to steal (move) the contents of the argument.

Comment: I suspect you've got to write the code of the two constructors according to how you want them to behave. If you want them to behave the same, then what's the point of defining the move ctor? Just define the copy ctor, and the move ctor will be deleted. You don't even want to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the code is the same for both since it's not a shallow copy, right?

The `List(const List &rhs)` **copy constructor** is expected to *deep copy* (not *shallow copy*) the *data* (not the nodes themselves) from `rhs` to `this`, but otherwise leave `rhs` intact and untouched.

The `List(List &&rhs)` **move constructor** is expected to *move* (steal) the nodes themselves from `rhs` to `this` and leave `rhs` in an empty state.

So, no, they would not be using the same code, not even close.

Same thing with the `operator=` **copy assignment** and **move assignment** operators (which are commonly implemented utilizing the copy/move constructors via the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/) to avoid code duplication).

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class List
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node *previous;
        node *next;
    };

    node *head = nullptr;
    node *tail = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;

public:
    // default constructor
    List() = default;

    // copy constructor
    List(const List &rhs)
    {
        node **newNode = &head;
        for(node *curNode = rhs.head; curNode; curNode = curNode->next)
        {
            *newNode = new node{curNode->data, tail, nullptr};
            tail = *newNode;
            ++size;
            newNode = &(tail->next);
        }
    }

    // move constructor
    List(List &&rhs)
        : head(rhs.head), tail(rhs.tail), size(rhs.size)
    {
        rhs.head = rhs.tail = nullptr;
        rhs.size = 0;
    }

    // destructor
    ~List()
    {
        node *curNode = head;
        while (curNode) {
            node *next = curNode->next;
            delete curNode;
            curNode = next;
        }
    }

    // copy assignment
    List& operator=(const List &rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            List tmp(rhs);
            std::swap(head, tmp.head);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment
    List& operator=(List &&rhs)
    {
        List tmp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(head, tmp.head);
        return *this;
    }

    /*
    Alternatively, you can use just 1 implementation of operator=
    for both copy and move assignments, by taking the input parameter
    *by value* and letting the compiler decide which constructor
    to call to initialize it, based on the type of input being assigned:

    // copy/move assignment
    List& operator=(List rhs)
    {
        List tmp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(head, tmp.head);
        return *this;
    }
    */
};
```

An operation like `L1 = L2 + L3` would have to implement `operator+` that takes 2 `List` objects as input and returns a new `List` object with *data* (not nodes) that is *copied* from both `L2` and `L3`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class List
{
    ...
public:
    ...

    List& operator+=(const List &rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.head) {
            List tmp(rhs);
            node **ptr = (tail) ? &(tail->next) : &head;
            *ptr = tmp.head; tmp.head = nullptr;
            tail = tmp.tail; tmp.tail = nullptr;
            size += tmp.size;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // operator+ can be implemented either as a class member
    // using *this as the left-hand operand...
    List operator+(const List &rhs) const
    {
        List res(*this);
        res += rhs;
        return res;
    }
};

// Or, operator+ can be implemented as a non-member function...
List operator+(const List &lhs, const List &rhs)
{
    List res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}
```

The returned `List` would be a temporary object, aka an rvalue, which would then be assigned to `L1` using the `operator=(List&&)` *move assignment* operator (or, the `operator=(List)` assignment operator using the `List(List&&)` *move constructor*).

Comment: Obviously, you would need to implement `operator+` before you can test `L1 = L2 + L3`.  But just to test the move (not copy) constructor, you can simply use something like this: `List<T> L1; add some nodes to L1 ...; List<T> L2(std::move(L1));`

Comment: Not for the constructors themselves, no.  Only for `operator=`.  This way, the caller can assign an lvalue or an rvalue, and the compiler will construct the `rhs` parameter using either the copy constructor or the move constructor, respectively. And then the `operator=` can simply move from `rhs`

Comment: The move constructor merely sets `this->head`/`this->tail` to point at the existing nodes in `rhs`, and then resets `rhs.head`/`rhs.tail` to `nullptr`, thus *stealing* the nodes from `rhs`. `this` is now responsible for managing the nodes that were previously managed by `rhs`. The nodes themselves stay in memory right where they are. **This is the whole point of move semantics.** `rhs` is not gone, merely reset to a "valid but indeterminate state" by the move constructor (or move assignment operator) - that state being an empty list - where `rhs` will be destructed at some later time.

Comment: @Zevias yes, that is exactly what you need to do. If `T` supports move semantics (`std::string`, etc) then `new Node(std::move(val))` will actually *move* `val`'s data into the node's data. Otherwise, if `T` does not support move semantics (`int`, etc), then `new Node(std::move(val))` will end up *copying* `val` instead. Either way, make sure that `Node` has a *move constructor* implemented.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I reread my provided List.h file and actually noticed my nested Node class (nested inside List) has a constructor as follows: ```Node(T && d, Node *p = nullptr, Node *n = nullptr): data{std::move(d)}, prev{p}, next{n} {}```. There is an identical one in place except it takes in a const &d rather than &&d. Does this mean my push_front move would not work when I call the Node constructor as ```Node(std::move(val),p,n)```t since the ```Node``` constructor already has a move for the data in one of the constructors or would it simply be redundant?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only doing a shallow copy, particularly of non-pointer values (or any other allocated resource), you should have no need for a move constructor.